# node js automatically convert GMT format date in MySQL to local format while querying records

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

In my node app, I have MySQL DB which has a column named xxx_date in GMT date format. I am querying the date field from DB using Node JS. The resulted data is in my local time format. I want the same data(in GMT). And I tried with changing my query with CONVERT_TZ method also. but the resulted data is mismatching. Someone suggest a right way do this.

for example

```
 xxx_date in DB: 2017-05-22 08:14:00
 the date I get after querying from DB: 2017-05-22T02:44:00.000Z
 but it should be either: 1:45 PM Monday, May 22, 2017, or  2017-05-22 08:14:00
```

what's happening behind this?

Answer (score 3):

After searching google for a day I found this. MySQL connection will take local timezone as default,(https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/262)  by changing it to UTC in config file we can get the data as same in DB.

In mysql connection

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  timezone:'UTC',
  port: 3307
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got correct date by setting prop `dateString` to true as mentioned https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/262#issuecomment-241604623